# Need help formatting output of command "xcrun simctl list devices"

Tags: bash, macos

### Intro

I have the output of the command `xcrun simctl list devices` on a file called `simulators.txt`:

```
-- iOS 13.1 --
    iPhone 11 (50E46560-28EE-4689-B015-01E86D9A2C8A) (Shutdown)
-- iOS 14.5 --
    iPhone 12 Pro (8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795) (Booted) 
-- iOS 16.2 --
    iPhone 12 Pro (21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04) (Booted) 
    iPhone 14 Pro (62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817) (Booted)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 --
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

My goal is to output this by filtering devices that are `Booted`:

```
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 14.5, 8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795)
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 16.2, 21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04)
* iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.2, 62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817)
```

Note that I need to preserve the model, version and UUId.

---

### Things that I've tried so far

#### Using sed:

`sed -ne 's/^-- iOS \(.*\) --/iOS \1:/p' -ne 's/^[ \t]*\(.*\) (Booted)/  * \1/p' < simulators.txt`

I get:

```
iOS 13.1:
iOS 14.5:
  * iPhone 12 Pro (8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795) 
iOS 16.2:
  * iPhone 12 Pro (21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04) 
  * iPhone 14 Pro (62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817)
```

I would need to save the capture group from the first match (`^-- iOS \(.*\) --`) to a variable and apply it on the second match, but I'm not sure how to do that.

#### Using bash function

```bash
function displaySimulators {
    while IFS="" read -r p; do
        if [[ "$p" =~ --\ iOS.*\ -- ]]; then
            IOS_VERSION=$(echo $p | sed -ne 's/^-- \(.*\) --/\1/p')
        else
            echo $p | sed -ne 's/^[ \t]*\(.*\) (\(.*\)) (Booted)/* \1 ('"$IOS_VERSION"', \2)/p'
        fi
    done < simulators.txt
}
```

Here you can see that I applied the idea of saving the first match to a variable and reusing it when necessary.

The output is:

```
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 14.5, 8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795)
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 16.2, 21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04)
* iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.2, 62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817)
```

Which is what I need, but then some questions come to mind.

---

### Questions

1. How can I make the bash solution better? Are there any good practices or another approach that is faster and cleaner than this?
2. How to achieve the same result using just `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: The main thing that's icky about the bash function is the use of `sed`. If you're going to use `=~`, go all the way and use `BASH_REMATCH` to extract match groups.

Comment: And `echo $p` is itself buggy; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). Always, _always_, **always** quote your parameter expansions: `echo "$p"`

Comment: (much less importantly -- as a portability thing not a correctness thing -- stay away from the legacy ksh `function funcname {` syntax; the modern POSIX-defined standards-compliant function syntax is `funcname() {`)

Comment: btw, also consider storing your regexes in variables and using `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`; more forgiving and portable across bash releases that way.

Comment: With `awk`, search for lines containing the string `(Booted)` and then throw away the last field (i.e. print all fields but the last).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your insightful overview, i will make some changes with your suggestions

Comment: I won't address the opinions you asked for but here's how to do what you need using any awk: `awk 'gsub(/^-- | --$/,""){ver=$0} sub(/ \(Booted).*/,""){sub(/[^()]+)/,ver", &"); $1="* "$1; print}' file`. If the question gets reopened I'll move that to an answer. That assumes the version such as in `-- iOS 13.1 --` can't contain `&` - if it can then include that case in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or just use `awk` and do it in one shot :

> ```
> mawk '(NF *= /^--/ ? "_"(__ = $2) : /[(]Booted[)]/) && 
>         $2 = $2 " " __'   FS='^[ -]+|[ -]+$|[)]? [(]|[)]? (--|[(][^(]+)$'
> ```

---

```
 iPhone 12 Pro iOS 14.5 8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795 
 iPhone 12 Pro iOS 16.2 21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04 
 iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.2 62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817
```

to handle the annoying case of the `iPhone SE (3rd generation)` (assuming it's flagged `"Booted"`), you have to expand the logic by a tiny bit

> ```
> gawk '(NF *= /^--/ ? "_" (__ = $2) : /[(]Booted[)]/) && 
>         $2 = $2 (4 < NF ? " (" $3 ") " : " ")__'  \
>           \
>       FS='^[ -]+|[ -]+$|[)]? [(]|[)]? (--|[(][^(]+)$'
> ```

---

```
 iPhone 12 Pro iOS 14.5 8F7AF263-396D-4256-803A-937FBC944795 
 iPhone 12 Pro iOS 16.2 21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04 
 iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.2 62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817 
 iPhone SE (3rd generation) Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 3rd generation 809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138
```

*caveat : this solution has an extra leading edge space*

Comment: Could you help me understand what is going on with the capture groups?

Comment: @EdYuTo : there were absolutely no capturing groups in my regex at all

Comment: I meant the use of your (what i think are) variables $2. `"_"(__ = $2)`

Comment: Also, i wasn't considering the `(3rd generation)` scenario, I appreciate the addition.

Answer (score 1):

- Assumption:

  Under the `Unavailable:` has `Shutdown` below/under it.

---

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

---

The `script.ed` name it to your own hearts content.

```
g?Booted?;?iOS?,t.
g/Shutdown/d
g?Booted?;?iOS?;+j
v/Booted/d
,s/ (Booted)//
g/./s/-- //g\
s/ --//g\
s/[[:space:]]\{2,\}/ /g
,s/^\(iOS [[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\(.*(\)\(.*\)/*\2\1, \3/
,p
Q
```

---

The `simulators.txt` and its content.

```
-- iOS 13.1 --
    iPhone 30 (33E46888-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2321) (Booted)
    iPhone 11 (50E46560-28EE-4689-B015-01E86D9A2C8A) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 25 (65446563-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2XYA) (Booted)
    iPhone 25 (2AC46563-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2BDP) (Booted)
    iPhone 18 (10E46563-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2C8Z) (Shutdown)
-- iOS 14.5 --
    iPhone 12 Pro (8F7AF263-396D-8256-803A-337FBC944795) (Booted)
    iPhone 16 Pro (9F7AF263-596D-7256-803A-537FBC944796) (Booted)
    iPhone 19 Pro (5F7AF263-996D-2256-803A-437FBC944797) (Booted)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 --
    iPhone SE (10th generation) (809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone SE (11t generation) (809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- iOS 16.2 --
    iPhone 12 Pro (21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04) (Booted)
    iPhone 14 Pro (62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817) (Booted)
    iPhone 15 Pro (72CDkABB-9552-2C79-B137-Z02A50867819) (Booted)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 --
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (809AF9A3-5F67-4083-AF66-4F3B4C7B2138) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

---

Run:

```
ed -s simulators.txt < script.ed
```

---

Output

```
* iPhone 30 (iOS 13.1, 33E46888-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2321)
* iPhone 25 (iOS 13.1, 65446563-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2XYA)
* iPhone 25 (iOS 13.1, 2AC46563-38EE-9689-7015-01E86D9A2BDP)
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 14.5, 8F7AF263-396D-8256-803A-337FBC944795)
* iPhone 16 Pro (iOS 14.5, 9F7AF263-596D-7256-803A-537FBC944796)
* iPhone 19 Pro (iOS 14.5, 5F7AF263-996D-2256-803A-437FBC944797)
* iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 16.2, 21CB340E-A08A-416A-BC28-78E26E42FC04)
* iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.2, 62BA4ADD-7441-4D62-B137-C02A50867817)
* iPhone 15 Pro (iOS 16.2, 72CDkABB-9552-2C79-B137-Z02A50867819)
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in_place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.
- See GNU [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- See POSIX [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `ed`  line editor, but rn i won't be able to use it. Thanks for the detailed example